# Uno PWM freq conflicts with other PORTs

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm

Am working on a small project in which I can control the speed a 24V DC Motor using a Variable resistance to A/D then generate the right PWM to an optocoupler while displaying the speed in 4 7-segments, the problem is the PWM (PORTD Pin 5) pin 5 on the Uno is not working when I Initialize any pin of PORTB (7-segment port)

```
int main(void)
{
  uint8 duty_cycle = 0, digit_t = 0, digit_h = 0, digit_ten = 0, digit = 0, read_index = 0, duty_old = 0;
  uint16 old_reading = 0, motor_rpm, read_average = 0;
  uint32 adc_readings = 0;
  /* Declare the 4 7-segments in the system */
  //    BCD_Segment seg_1, seg_2, seg_3, seg_4;

  //    /* Initialize the 7-segments */
  //    Segment_Init(&seg_1, B, pin0, pin1, pin2, pin3, D, pin0);
  //    Segment_Init(&seg_2, B, pin0, pin1, pin2, pin3, D, pin1);
  //    Segment_Init(&seg_3, B, pin0, pin1, pin2, pin3, D, pin2);
  //    Segment_Init(&seg_4, B, pin0, pin1, pin2, pin3, D, pin3);
  //    //
  //    ///* Turn off segments */
  //    //Segment_OFF(&seg_1);
  //    //Segment_OFF(&seg_2);
  //    //Segment_OFF(&seg_3);
  //    //Segment_OFF(&seg_4);
  /* segment pins */
  //SET_BIT(DDRB, 0);
  //SET_BIT(DDRB, 1);
  //SET_BIT(DDRB, 2);
  //SET_BIT(DDRB, 3);

    /* Enable pins */
SET_BIT(DDRD, 0);
SET_BIT(DDRD, 1);
SET_BIT(DDRD, 2);
SET_BIT(DDRD, 3);

  /* display 0*/
  //CLEAR_BIT(PORTB, 0);
  //CLEAR_BIT(PORTB, 1);
  //CLEAR_BIT(PORTB, 2);
  //CLEAR_BIT(PORTB, 3);

  /* segments off */
  CLEAR_BIT(PORTD, 0);
  CLEAR_BIT(PORTD, 1);
  CLEAR_BIT(PORTD, 2);
  CLEAR_BIT(PORTD, 3);

  uint16 adc_reading = 0;
  Boolean adc_flag = False;
  /* Declare the 4 7-segments in the system */

  /* Initialize the adc and the pwm timer */
  ADC_init();
  PWM_Init();

  while (1)
    {
      ADC_StartConversion();
      adc_flag = ADC_WaitForFlag();

      /* calculate the ADC voltage */
      adc_reading = ADC_GetValue();

      if((adc_reading <= 256) && (adc_reading >= 0))
    {
      PWM_DutyCycle(0);
    }
      else if((adc_reading > 256) && (adc_reading <= 512))
    {
      PWM_DutyCycle(50);
    }
      else if((adc_reading < 768) && (adc_reading > 512))
    {
      PWM_DutyCycle(75);
    }
      else if(adc_reading >= 768)
    {
      PWM_DutyCycle(100);
    }

      /* Clear the ADC flag */
      ADC_ClearFlag();

      /* update the pwm */
      //PWM_DutyCycle(duty_cycle);
    }
}
```

[image: PWM working good at some ADC level]

and here the code for the bad PWM

```
    int main(void)
    {
      uint8 duty_cycle = 0, digit_t = 0, digit_h = 0, digit_ten = 0, digit = 0, read_index = 0, duty_old = 0;
       uint16 old_reading = 0, motor_rpm, read_average = 0;
  uint32 adc_readings = 0;
  /* Declare the 4 7-segments in the system */
  //    BCD_Segment seg_1, seg_2, seg_3, seg_4;

  //    /* Initialize the 7-segments */
  //    Segment_Init(&seg_1, B, pin0, pin1, pin2, pin3, D, pin0);
  //    Segment_Init(&seg_2, B, pin0, pin1, pin2, pin3, D, pin1);
  //    Segment_Init(&seg_3, B, pin0, pin1, pin2, pin3, D, pin2);
  //    Segment_Init(&seg_4, B, pin0, pin1, pin2, pin3, D, pin3);
  //    //
  //    ///* Turn off segments */
  //    //Segment_OFF(&seg_1);
  //    //Segment_OFF(&seg_2);
  //    //Segment_OFF(&seg_3);
  //    //Segment_OFF(&seg_4);

  /* segment pins */
  /* just enabling one pin or all fails the PWM on PORTD PIN 5*/
  SET_BIT(DDRB, 0);
  //SET_BIT(DDRB, 1);
  //SET_BIT(DDRB, 2);
  //SET_BIT(DDRB, 3);

    /* Enable pins */
SET_BIT(DDRD, 0);
SET_BIT(DDRD, 1);
SET_BIT(DDRD, 2);
SET_BIT(DDRD, 3);

  /* display 0*/
  //CLEAR_BIT(PORTB, 0);
  //CLEAR_BIT(PORTB, 1);
  //CLEAR_BIT(PORTB, 2);
  //CLEAR_BIT(PORTB, 3);

  /* segments off */
  CLEAR_BIT(PORTD, 0);
  CLEAR_BIT(PORTD, 1);
  CLEAR_BIT(PORTD, 2);
  CLEAR_BIT(PORTD, 3);

  uint16 adc_reading = 0;
  Boolean adc_flag = False;
  /* Declare the 4 7-segments in the system */

  /* Initialize the adc and the pwm timer */
  ADC_init();
  PWM_Init();

  while (1)
    {
      ADC_StartConversion();
      adc_flag = ADC_WaitForFlag();

      /* calculate the ADC voltage */
      adc_reading = ADC_GetValue();

      if((adc_reading <= 256) && (adc_reading >= 0))
    {
      PWM_DutyCycle(0);
    }
      else if((adc_reading > 256) && (adc_reading <= 512))
    {
      PWM_DutyCycle(50);
    }
      else if((adc_reading < 768) && (adc_reading > 512))
    {
      PWM_DutyCycle(75);
    }
      else if(adc_reading >= 768)
    {
      PWM_DutyCycle(100);
    }

      /* Clear the ADC flag */
      ADC_ClearFlag();

      /* update the pwm */
      //PWM_DutyCycle(duty_cycle);
    }
}
```

and the output is like this 
[image: PWM went Rogue]

Here's the code for PWM_Init

```
void PWM_Init(void)
{
  /* Making the pwm pin output */
  pinMode(pin5, D, Output);

  /* fast pwm mode */
  SET_BIT(TCCR0A, WGM00);
  SET_BIT(TCCR0A, WGM01);
  CLEAR_BIT(TCCR0A, WGM02);

  /* Inverting */
  SET_BIT(TCCR0A, COM0B1);
  SET_BIT(TCCR0A, COM0B0);

  /* prescaler 1024 */
  SET_BIT(TCCR0B, CS00);
  CLEAR_BIT(TCCR0B, CS01);
  SET_BIT(TCCR0B, CS02);
}

void PWM_DutyCycle(uint8_t duty)
{
  OCR0B = (duty * 255) / 100;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "bad PWM" means?

Comment: I used the fast PWM mode so the output should be continuous like the first pic, but when write to the DDRB in any pin the PWM output is like what appears in the last pic

Comment: Please show us your PWM code, like `PWM_Init()` and such

Comment: What is connected to pin 12?

Comment: I added the code for the PWM_Init() and PWM_DutyCycle()

Comment: for pin 12 it's not connected to anything and not even Initialized.

Comment: Re “`pinMode(pin5, D, Output);`”: you mean `pinMode(5, OUTPUT);`?

Comment: it means pin 5 of PORT D is output it writes to the DDRD register and this pin is pin5 on the UNO